# request.form() results in 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand

Tags: python, html, forms, flask, request

I have a sortable list as a webapp that is hooked to sqlite.
I want to add new entries to the list with a dragdown menu.
I fail to make the list entries a form that submits the new values.

app.py:

```
import sqlite3, logging
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for, flash, redirect, jsonify
from werkzeug.exceptions import abort


app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/static')
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'NotForYou'

def get_db_connection():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('/root/ilms/ilmh.db')
    conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    return conn

@app.route('/potm',methods=["POST","GET"])
def potm():
    conn = get_db_connection()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        Name = request.args['newPOTM']
        maxID = conn.execute('SELECT MAX(id) FROM POTM')
        newID = maxID + 1
        print(newID)
        maxOrder = conn.execute('SELECT MAX(listorder) FROM POTM')
        newOrder = maxOrder + 1
        print(newOrder)
        conn.execute('INSERT INTO POTM (id, player, listorder) VALUES (?, ?, ?)',
                     (newID, Name, newOrder))
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
        return redirect(url_for('potm'))
    dragdrop = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM POTM ORDER BY listorder ASC")
    dropdown = conn.execute('SELECT Name FROM alltime ORDER BY Name ASC').fetchall()
    return render_template('potm.html', dragdrop=dragdrop, dropdown=dropdown)
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Add Player
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu pre-scrollable" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
                <form method="POST">
                            {% for item in dropdown %}
                            <input type="text" class="dropdown-item" name="newPOTM" value="{{ item['Name'] }}" onclick=this.form.submit()>
                            </input>
                        {% endfor %}
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Dropdown and list shows up but when I click a list object it results in

> werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
> KeyError: 'newPOTM'

Comment: try `Name = request.form.get('newPOTM')` instead of `Name = request.args['newPOTM']`, or `Name = request.form['newPOTM'])`

Comment: @Ghost Ops Sorry, tried these before and started with request.form(). request.form.get results in  TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable. request.form results in the mentioned 400 error

Answer (score 0):

Got it working: I missed to define the form action. with request.form() I passed the problem.